# Is there a way to render/show pdf in my tablet application?

Tags: android, pdf

I am implementing a tablet application which at left side shows list of my pdf files and on the right side I want to show the pdf file data. How can I do that? I am curious if I could launch the pdf reader intent in a fragment so I launch another application on my own. Is it possible? Or If i should use some pdf render sdk,but the problem is that i need to avoid gpl license, and nearly all these kind of sdk, which i found are gpl licensed,in mobile version i simply open the installed pdf reader. Or can i open them in webview? something like the url will be a place in my file System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library). You will be able to display the `PDFs` in your `Fragments` or whatever you use. Although you should look at the source, and you'll maybe have to modify it, to take care of all the `AsynkTasks` that are running to "decode" the PDF files, and stop them properly.

You can't  integrate/start an external application via `Intent` and encapsulate it in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer I will check & try it, I have upvoted You. But the licensing is still GPL :(

Comment: I don't think you will be able to display a local PDF in a webview.